# Odd even number sum

Tags: pascal

I need to calculate odd/even sum, here is what I've got so far:

```
PROGRAM EvenOddSum;
USES
  WinCrt;
VAR
  odd, even, x: INTEGER;

  BEGIN

  WriteLn('Calculation of sum');
  WriteLn;
  odd := 0;
  even := 0;
  Write('Enter value(s)');
  WHILE x > 0 DO BEGIN
   IF x mod 2:= 0 THEN BEGIN
     even := even + x;
   ELSE
     odd := odd + x;

  ReadLn(x);
  END;
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn('Even sum is = ', even);
  WriteLn('Odd sum is =', odd);
  END.
```

I use freepascal.org compiler and I get this error :

```
SYNTAX error THEN expected but := found
```

And I just can't see the problem with this code.

Comment: Last time I wrote Pascal was 1983, but are you sure you need the BEGIN keyword after THEN?  I recall that BEGIN introduces an instruction block like { does in C/C++/Java/C#.

Comment: @EricJ. I guess so http://wiki.freepascal.org/IF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pascal, `:=` is the assignment operator. Replace it with `=` on the line that reads `IF x mod 2:= 0 THEN BEGIN`.

Also, remove the `BEGIN`. The result should read:

```
IF x mod 2 = 0 THEN
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in here:

```
IF x mod 2:= 0 THEN BEGIN
```

The `:=`  is used for assignment, use '=' or '==' for comparison. 
(Off the top of my head, I don't know if Pascal uses '=', '==', or both for comparisons. One of them should do the trick).

Answer (score 1):

If am not wrong, **`:=`** is used for declaring & assigning the value. For condition, you should use **`=`** .

change **`x mod 2:= 0`** to **`x mod 2 = 0`**

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

`x mod 2 > 0 then writeln(x);`

This will print all the odd numbers.